# How I can break wordpress loop after 6 items and then continue with the rest items

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, break

I have a wordpress taxonomy category filter displayed with this code

```
<?php                               
$video_args = array(                                        
    'hide_empty' => true,                                       
    'fields' => 'all',                                      
    'hierarchical' => true,                     
    'orderby' => 'term_order',                                      
    'child_of' => 0,                                        
    'get' => '',                                        
    'name__like' => '',                                     
    'pad_counts' => false,                                      
    'taxonomy' => 'video-category',                                     
    'cache_domain' => 'core'                                
);      
$coount = 1;
$v_terms = get_terms('video-category', $video_args);    
foreach ($v_terms as $v_term) {                     
    $term_link = get_term_link($v_term, 'video-category'); 
    if($coount < 7){
         ?>                                         
         <li class="video_<?php echo $v_term->term_id; ?>_term" id="<?php echo $coount++ ?>">                               
             <a id="<?php echo $v_term->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $v_term->name; ?></a>                               
             <span class="active_tab_border"></span>                            
         </li>
     <?php } else { ?>
         </ul><li class='restcats'>
         <ul class='restcat_list'>
              <li class="video_<?php echo $v_term->term_id; ?>_term" id="<?php echo $coount++ ?>">                              
                  <a id="<?php echo $v_term->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $v_term->name; ?></a>                              
                  <span class="active_tab_border"></span>                           
              </li>
              </ul>
              </li>
     <?php }

       } $coount++                  
      ?>
```

I need to break a loop after 6 items and then wrap items starting from 7 to another div and gave another style.With mine code it is not working properly, it created one for each next item.

Comment: count++ should be inside foreach loop and you forgot to insert semicolon ";" after coount

Comment: I moved it but now it works in very different way

Comment: try to echo coount value to check if it is braking after six, if it is breaking after six then it might be some problem with your tags or css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put you items after 7 outside the loop.

```
<?php                               
                            $video_args = array(                                        
                                'hide_empty' => true,                                       
                                'fields' => 'all',                                      
                                'hierarchical' => true,                     
                                'orderby' => 'term_order',                                      
                                'child_of' => 0,                                        
                                'get' => '',                                        
                                'name__like' => '',                                     
                                'pad_counts' => false,                                      
                                'taxonomy' => 'video-category',                                     
                                'cache_domain' => 'core'                                
                                );      
                                $coount = 1;
                            $v_terms = get_terms('video-category', $video_args);    
                            foreach ($v_terms as $v_term) {                     
                                $term_link = get_term_link($v_term, 'video-category'); 
                                if($coount < 7){
                                ?>                                          
                        <li class="video_<?php echo $v_term->term_id; ?>_term" id="<?php echo $coount++ ?>">                                
                            <a id="<?php echo $v_term->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $v_term->name; ?></a>                                
                            <span class="active_tab_border"></span>                         
                        </li>
                            <?php  }else{?>
                     <?php if($coount == '7') { ?>  
                     </ul><li class='restcats'>
                           <ul class='restcat_list'>
                      <?php } ?>

                                <li class="video_<?php echo $v_term->term_id; ?>_term" id="<?php echo $coount++ ?>">                                
                                    <a id="<?php echo $v_term->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $v_term->name; ?></a>                                
                                    <span class="active_tab_border"></span>                         
                                </li>

                        <?php if(($coount-1) == count($v_terms)){ ?>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                        <?php } 
                             }

                            }    $coount++;                  
                            ?>
```

Comment: It helps but now the 7th item is missing I tried to change the if to $coount <= 6 but didnt helped

Comment: now it created 2 uls not one with the rest categories inside

Comment: How many URLs do you have? Also what is wrong with the output you are getting now?

Comment: how I can wrap the all rest to the second ul @Tarun Upadhyay?

Comment: Not URL I want to wrap the rest categories into the second UL,create one UL for the rest

Comment: Do you want to wrap all rest into <ul class='restcat_list'>?

Comment: Try edited answer now. If doesnt work try replacing this if(($coount-1) == with if(($coount) ==

Comment: it created 2 LI again

Comment: it created one with correct and one with last category

Comment: Yes there will be 2 or as many LIs inside 1 UL for greater than records

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85004/discussion-between-tarun-upadhyay-and-anahit-dev).

Comment: Listen now it created 1 for first 6 and 2 LI , first of 2 Li containes right categories and the second contained only 1 last category.How I can remove that one?

Comment: I removed it with css but wanted to have a clean code.Can you help me wth it/